# How do I create a new column in a dataframe from an existing column using conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have one column containing all the data which looks something like this (values that need to be separated have a mark like (c)):

```
UK (c)
London
Wales
Liverpool
US (c)
Chicago
New York
San Francisco
Seattle
Australia (c)
Sydney
Perth
```

And I want it split into two columns looking like this:

```
London          UK
Wales           UK
Liverpool       UK
Chicago         US
New York        US
San Francisco   US
Seattle         US
Sydney          Australia
Perth           Australia
```

Question 2: What if the countries did not have a pattern like (c)?

Comment: It's a somewhat interesting string manipulation problem and by this tag's usual standards a relatively decent question with sample data and clearly specified expected output. I'm not complaining ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step by step with `endswith` and `ffill` + `str.strip`

```
df['country']=df.loc[df.city.str.endswith('(c)'),'city']
df.country=df.country.ffill()
df=df[df.city.ne(df.country)]
df.country=df.country.str.strip('(c)')
```

Comment: What if the countries did not have a pattern like (c)?

Comment: @Tsatsa in that case you may need build a country list , and using `isin`

Answer (score 7):

#### `extract` and `ffill`

Start with `extract` and `ffill`, then remove redundant rows.

```
df['country'] = (
    df['data'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s+\(c\)', expand=False).ffill())
df[~df['data'].str.contains('(c)', regex=False)].reset_index(drop=True)

            data    country
0         London         UK
1          Wales         UK
2      Liverpool         UK
3        Chicago         US
4       New York         US
5  San Francisco         US
6        Seattle         US
7         Sydney  Australia
8          Perth  Australia
```

Where,

```
df['data'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s+\(c\)', expand=False).ffill()

0            UK
1            UK
2            UK
3            UK
4            US
5            US
6            US
7            US
8            US
9     Australia
10    Australia
11    Australia
Name: country, dtype: object
```

The pattern `'(.*)\s+\(c\)'` matches strings of the form "country (c)" and extracts the country name. Anything not matching this pattern is replaced with NaN, so you can conveniently forward fill on rows.

---

#### `split` with `np.where` and `ffill`

This splits on "(c)".

```
u = df['data'].str.split(r'\s+\(c\)')
df['country'] = pd.Series(np.where(u.str.len() == 2, u.str[0], np.nan)).ffill()

df[~df['data'].str.contains('(c)', regex=False)].reset_index(drop=True)

            data    country
0         London         UK
1          Wales         UK
2      Liverpool         UK
3        Chicago         US
4       New York         US
5  San Francisco         US
6        Seattle         US
7         Sydney  Australia
8          Perth  Australia
```

Comment: `extract('(.*)\s+\(c\)')` saves you from `.str.strip()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can first use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to locate the cities ending in `(c)` and extract the country name, and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to populate a new `country` column.

The same extracted matches can be use to locate the rows to be dropped, i.e. rows which are [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
m = df.city.str.extract('^(.*?)(?=\(c\)$)')
ix = m[m.squeeze().notna()].index
df['country'] = m.ffill()
df.drop(ix)

            city     country
1          London         UK 
2           Wales         UK 
3       Liverpool         UK 
5         Chicago         US 
6        New York         US 
7   San Francisco         US 
8         Seattle         US 
10         Sydney  Australia 
11          Perth  Australia
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) too:

```
mask = df['places'].str.contains('(c)', regex = False)
df['country'] = np.where(mask, df['places'], np.nan)
df['country'] = df['country'].str.replace('\(c\)', '').ffill()
df = df[~mask]
df
            places     country
1          London         UK 
2           Wales         UK 
3       Liverpool         UK 
5         Chicago         US 
6        New York         US 
7   San Francisco         US 
8         Seattle         US 
10         Sydney  Australia 
11          Perth  Australia
```

The str contains looks for `(c)` and if present will return True for that index. Where this condition is True, the country value will be added to the country columns

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
data = ['UK (c)','London','Wales','Liverpool','US (c)','Chicago','New York','San Francisco','Seattle','Australia (c)','Sydney','Perth']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['city'])
df['country'] = df.city.apply(lambda x : x.replace('(c)','') if '(c)' in x else None)
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df = df[df['city'].str.contains('\(c\)')==False]
```

**Output**

```
+-----+----------------+-----------+
|     |     city       |  country  |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
|  1  | London         | UK        |
|  2  | Wales          | UK        |
|  3  | Liverpool      | UK        |
|  5  | Chicago        | US        |
|  6  | New York       | US        |
|  7  | San Francisco  | US        |
|  8  | Seattle        | US        |
| 10  | Sydney         | Australia |
| 11  | Perth          | Australia |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
```